# How implement https connection between .net core Web-Application and Web-API

Tags: http, ssl, iis, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I have some trouble connecting my .net core Web-Application with my .net core Web-Api via https.
Server 1: Win 12 Server; IIS 8.5; .net Core Web-Application
Server 2: Win 12 Server; IIS 8.5; .net Core Web-API

Http connection works fine, so I gernerated a "self sign Certificate" in IIS of Server 2, changed http binding to https using my Certificate.

In Server 1 I added the Certifacte to "trusted root certificates" and changed the url for the calling Web-Application ("https://server2:9999/controller/action).

I am getting a statuscode 502, so what am I missing?

I would be very grateful for any hint.

Comment: Are you using Kestrel or WebListener? If Kestrel, [have you added listening to https port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x)? `.UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, <port>, listenOptions =>
            { 
                listenOptions.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", "testPassword");
            });
        })`

Comment: Yes I am using Kestrel. Just for my understanding. I need to add this to my Web-Api so it will "listen to https requests"? Anyway thanks a lot for the advice i´ll try it.